# NR_CPUS define translated to 8192 during kernel compilation

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile 4.14 Linux kernel for Ubuntu 18.04, with some minor changes I've made in the code (not relevant to the discussion).

From some reason the `NR_CPUS` define translates to number 8192 for me, which is a way too big number, and it messes up with my code. (I have only 4 CPU cores on my Kabylake machine). Why is it so big? Did I miss something in the configs before I tried to compile the kernel? How do I change the definition correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your kernel tree, check arch/x86/Kconfig to see which kernel options you've set from menuconfig may be affecting Kabylake NR_CPUS.  According to my 4.14.2 version of this Kconfig:

```
config NR_CPUS
        int "Maximum number of CPUs" if SMP && !MAXSMP
        range 2 8 if SMP && X86_32 && !X86_BIGSMP
        range 2 512 if SMP && !MAXSMP && !CPUMASK_OFFSTACK
        range 2 8192 if SMP && !MAXSMP && CPUMASK_OFFSTACK && X86_64
        default "1" if !SMP
        default "8192" if MAXSMP
        default "32" if SMP && X86_BIGSMP
        default "8" if SMP && X86_32
        default "64" if SMP
        ---help---
          This allows you to specify the maximum number of CPUs which this
          kernel will support.  If CPUMASK_OFFSTACK is enabled, the maximum
          supported value is 8192, otherwise the maximum value is 512.  The
          minimum value which makes sense is 2.
```

So setting MAXSMP (appears in menuconfig session as "Enable Maximum number of SMP Processors and NUMA Nodes [N/y]") could be getting you to 8192.  Note that with NR_CPUS you are specifying the **maximum** number of CPUs to be used with this kernel; it's not expected to match your current CPU count exactly.  That should be done on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your ".config" directly or change it using menuconfig from kernel directory (Under kernel-features) . NR_CPUS defaults to 4 only. Not sure how u ended up 8192. Better share your kernel defconfig so that much can be commented